# JQuery AJAX failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX call executes and returns what I want it too but not within .done 
It fails under .fail and results work in .always

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){

            var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSON_MDB_UPDATE.php",
                data: formData
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert( "Done: " + data );
                data = $.trim(data);
                $("#notification").text(data.responseText);
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert("Failed: " + data);
                console.log(data);
            })
            .always(function(data) { 
                $("#notification").text(data.responseText);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

here is my console results:

[image: console.log]

My PHP is just a simple example echo:

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");


$firstName = $_POST[firstName];
$lastName = $_POST[lastName];

echo("My First Name: " . $firstName . " Last Name: " . $lastName);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

This says you are outputting JSON, so jQuery will attempt to parse it as JSON and fall to the error state if it can't.

> `echo("My First Name: " . $firstName . " Last Name: " . $lastName);`

This is **not** JSON

Output JSON instead.

```
echo json_encode(Array("My First Name" => $firstName, "Last Name" => $lastName));
```

---

Alternatively, if you do not want structured data: Don't say you are sending JSON:

```
header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, as you can tell I'm new to this... Both your examples solve my problem... many thanks!